# Custom highlighter in ios-chart

Tags: swift2, ios-charts

I am working on a custom chart, which is somewhat like scatter chart. I am plotting events against, date in x axis and time (24 hours) in y axis. So in a single day there can be multiple values in y axis. 
I am done with the chart, but the highlighter does not work properly for obvious reasons. I was able to create my custom highlighter in android and assign that as a highlighter to the chart. But in the ios-library, the highlighter classes are declared as internal, and I cannot override the highlighter, OR assign a custom highlighter to the chart.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can override the highlighter, I already did that.

You just need to sub class the chart view and replace it with your highlighter in `initialize`

Internal just limit its visibility in the same module/framework

Comment: How do you suggest I replace the highlighter! cannot override _highlighter.

Comment: subclass the chart view

Comment: how do you override _highlighter in the subclass? I am already subclassing chartview. But cannot access _highlighter

Comment: check out initialize function, we replace it there

Comment: I can override initialize function no problem with that. But when I set `_highlighter = CustomHighlighter(chart: self)` it says undefined variable _highlighter!

Comment: which version of the library are you using? It is just an internal variable, if you are not in the same module/framework, you cannot see it

Comment: if this is the case, you have to grab the source code and use it; or you change the internal to public and compile it as framework in your project.